# Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: nginx) Error

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt, ubuntu-20.04, certbot

This is my first time building a server and hosting it to AWS EC2

Let me brief what I have done till now :

Step 1 : I mapped my EC2 ipv4 address to domain (say week10.100xdevs.com)

Step 2 : Then I opened sudo vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
and inserted this code :

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name week10.100xdevs.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
}
```

Step 3: I did pm2 start index.js on my server file.

Step 4: Then I installed certbot using sudo snap install --classic certbot

Step 5: Prepared certbot using sudo ln -s /snap/bin/certbot /usr/bin/certbot

Step 6: Finally I did , sudo certbot --nginx

And I get this error :

```
sudo certbot --nginx
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

Which names would you like to activate HTTPS for?
We recommend selecting either all domains, or all domains in a VirtualHost/server block.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: week10.100xdevs.com
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Select the appropriate numbers separated by commas and/or spaces, or leave input
blank to select all options shown (Enter 'c' to cancel): 1
Requesting a certificate for week10.100xdevs.com

Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: nginx). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: week10.100xdevs.com
  Type:   connection
  Detail: 3.88.225.115: Fetching http://week10.100xdevs.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/apVWIX8WnEim8VNlAaYc7_mfI2PXAtJ2RLF-1kqEfKc: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to verify the temporary nginx configuration changes made by Certbot. Ensure the listed domains point to this nginx server and that it is accessible from the internet.

Some challenges have failed.
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
```

How to fix this error ?

Now after too many attempts I am getting :

```
Plugins selected: Authenticator nginx, Installer nginx

Which names would you like to activate HTTPS for?
We recommend selecting either all domains, or all domains in a VirtualHost/server block.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: week10.100xdevs.com
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Select the appropriate numbers separated by commas and/or spaces, or leave input
blank to select all options shown (Enter 'c' to cancel): 1
Requesting a certificate for week10.100xdevs.com
An unexpected error occurred:
Error creating new order :: too many failed authorizations recently: see https://letsencrypt.org/docs/failed-validation-limit/
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to own the domain to generate certificate for it. I was generating for the EC2 url which was wrong. Certbot verifies if someone actually owns a domain, we need to provide domain ownership to certbot to be able to generate a certificate for that specific domain.